# Successful message not received on device

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send the push notification to my android device using firebase,I am calling the firebase api with post parameter,when I call the api it gives me 200ok, but in my device I am not receiving any notification. I tried with same device token using firebase console website and here I am able to send it and its coming in my device, Below is my call of node js

```
request({
url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
method: 'POST',
headers: {'Content-Type' :' application/json','Authorization': 'key=AA'},
body: JSON.stringify({ 
"to" : deviceId,
"priority": "high",
"notification": {
"message": message,
"body": "ipl matches are there",
"title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
"text": "5 to 1"
 },}),
```

Can any one please let me know what is wrong here.
thanks

Comment: Hi. Do post the client side code for handling the message.

Comment: @AL. I am using cordova to register my device and that token I am using to call this api,that is the only code I have,I don't understand what do you mean by client side code,Can you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved for android device by passing below body:

```
   {
   "notification": {
   "message": message,
   "title": "teri ma ki",
   "text": "this is for testing"
   },
   "to" : deviceId
```

}

let other parameters as given in question.